# grepl repetition of upperbound and plus character

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I am working on a data frame (`df`) which looks like this and can contain more than 10000 rows for some cases.

```
   Object                            Coding Fn Remaining
1  T00055                T 00055_005_<002_+  2        30
2  T00055                T 00055_008_<002_+  2        30
3  E00336           E 00336_041_<001_+001_+  3         0
4  E00336      E 00336_041_<001_+001_+001_+  4        10
5  E00336      E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_+  4        56
6  E00336      E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_<  4        52
7 T 00054 T 00054_013_<003_<015_+003_<001_<  4        52
```

I need to `grep` all rows which contain **at least** twice `_+` in the string of the column `Coding` in order to get a data frame `test`.

I am trying :

```
test<-filter(df,
             grepl("_[+].{2,}",Coding))
```

which cannot exclude the last row.  Any idea why?  Many thanks

here is the results:

```
   Object                            Coding Fn Remaining
1  E00336           E 00336_041_<001_+001_+  3         0
2  E00336      E 00336_041_<001_+001_+001_+  4        10
3  E00336      E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_+  4        56
4  E00336      E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_<  4        52
5 T 00054 T 00054_013_<003_<015_+003_<001_<  4        52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
df <- structure(list(Object = c("T00055", "T00055", "E00336", "E00336",
"E00336", "E00336", "T 00054"), Coding = c("T 00055_005_<002_+",
"T 00055_008_<002_+", "E 00336_041_<001_+001_+", "E 00336_041_<001_+001_+001_+",
"E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_+", "E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_<",
"T 00054_013_<003_<015_+003_<001_<"), Fn = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L), Remaining = c(30L, 30L, 0L, 10L, 56L, 52L, 52L)), .Names = c("Object",
"Coding", "Fn", "Remaining"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

subset(df, grepl(rex(at_least(group("_+", anything), 2)), Coding))

#>   Object                       Coding Fn Remaining
#> 3 E00336      E 00336_041_<001_+001_+  3         0
#> 4 E00336 E 00336_041_<001_+001_+001_+  4        10
#> 5 E00336 E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_+  4        56
#> 6 E00336 E 00336_041_<001_+001_+002_<  4        52
```

Comment: Either work similarly, although the rex function brings simplicity.

Comment: However both solutions (Jim's and @Sven Hohenstein) are not able to find this type of string "T 00266_003_+003_+005_<005_+043_+009_<018_<010_+016_+001_<002_<001_+" or this one
"T 00266/T 00554_044_+006_+003_+028_+014_<005_<005_+001_+003_>002_+"  Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, `grepl(rex(at_least(group("_+", anything), 2)), "T 00266_003_+003_+005_<005_+043_+009_<018_<010_+016_+001_<002_<001_+")` -> `TRUE` on my machine

Comment: Ok my bad ! my problem has to have another origin. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command:

```
subset(df, grepl("(_\\+.*){2,}", Coding))
```

or, with `dplyr`,

```
filter(df, grepl("(_\\+.*){2,}", Coding))
```

Your current regex, `"_[+].{2,}"`, matches `_+` followed by at least two characters. You need to create a group using parentheses in order to correctly apply the quantifier.

Comment: @KK_63 Ist there a problem with this code? Why do you no longer accept this answer?